# Area under the "pdf" in kernel density estimation in R

Tags: r, estimation, density-function, kernel-smoothing, auc

I am trying to use the '[density](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/density.html)' function in R to do kernel density estimates. I am having some difficulty interpreting the results and comparing various datasets as it seems the area under the curve is not necessarily 1. For any [probability density function (pdf)](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Probability_density_function) $\phi(x)$, we need to have the area $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x) dx = 1$. I am assuming that the kernel density estimate reports the pdf. I am using [integrate.xy](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/sfsmisc/html/integrate.xy.html) from [sfsmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sfsmisc/index.html) to estimate the area under the curve.

```
> # generate some data
> xx<-rnorm(10000)
> # get density
> xy <- density(xx)
> # plot it
> plot(xy)
```

[image: plot of the density]

```
> # load the library
> library(sfsmisc)
> integrate.xy(xy$x,xy$y)
[1] 1.000978
> # fair enough, area close to 1
> # use another bw
> xy <- density(xx,bw=.001)
> plot(xy)
```

[image: density with bw= .001]

```
> integrate.xy(xy$x,xy$y)
[1] 6.518703
> xy <- density(xx,bw=1)
> integrate.xy(xy$x,xy$y)
[1] 1.000977
> plot(xy)
```

[image: density with bw = 1]

```
> xy <- density(xx,bw=1e-6)
> integrate.xy(xy$x,xy$y)
[1] 6507.451
> plot(xy)
```

[image: density with bw=1e-6]

Shouldn't the area under the curve always be 1? It seems small bandwidths are a problem, but sometimes you want to show the details etc. in the tails and small bandwidths are needed.

**Update/Answer:**

It seems that the answer below about the overestimation in convex regions is correct as increasing the number of integration points seems to lessen the problem (I didn't try to use more than $2^{20}$ points.)

```
> xy <- density(xx,n=2^15,bw=.001)
> plot(xy)
```

[image: density with higher number of points to sample at]

```
> integrate.xy(xy$x,xy$y)
[1] 1.000015
> xy <- density(xx,n=2^20,bw=1e-6)
> integrate.xy(xy$x,xy$y)
[1] 2.812398
```

---

Comment: This looks like a floating point limitation in density(): in using a bandwidth of 1e-6, you are creating (in theory) a collection of 10,000 spikes, each of total mass 1/10000.  Those spikes end up being represented primarily by their peaks, without the gaps being adequately characterized.  You're merely pushing density() beyond its limits.

Comment: @whuber, by floating point limitation, do you mean limits of the precision, as in using floats would lead to greater overestimation of the error compared to using doubles. I don't think I see how that would happen but would like to see some evidence.

Comment: Your update demonstrates that convexity is *not* the issue; the issue lies in using too small a value of $n$ in the density calculation.

Comment: Shouldn't the integral value of a *proper* density estimate be $1$?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, yes, that is what this question is asking. Why is it not evaluating to 1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think about the trapezoid rule `integrate.xy()` uses. For the normal distribution, it will *underestimate* the area under the curve in the interval (-1,1) where the density is concave (and hence the linear interpolation is below the true density), and *overestimate* it elsewhere (as the linear interpolation goes on top of the true density). Since the latter region is larger (in Lesbegue measure, if you like), the trapezoid rule tends to overestimate the integral. Now, as you move to smaller bandwidths, pretty much all of your estimate is piecewise convex, with a lot of narrow spikes corresponding to the data points, and valleys between them. That's where the trapezoid rule breaks down especially badly.

Comment: that means that we are "oversampling" the peaks and "undersampling" the valleys, in some hand-wavy sense. Since the visualization also follows the trapezoidal rule (linear interpolation across samples), it seems too small a kernel bandwidth is also bad for visualization. Also, if we could get a larger number of points at which we calculate the density, there would be less of a problem.

Comment: This explanation does not hold water.  The problem is that the density is inadequately discretized, not that the trapezoid rule breaks down badly.  integrate() is helpless to get a correct answer because density() does not produce a correct representation.  To see this, just inspect xy$x: it has only 512 values intended to represent 10,000 narrow spikes!

Comment: @whuber, that's what the answer said. The point is you need to use the trapezoidal rule for finite number of samples, and it overestimates the area compared to the true density on a continuous axis according to the kernels. My update at the end of the question expands on it.

Comment: @high No; the trapezoidal rule is working fine.  The problem is that it is working with an incorrect discretization of the integrand.  You can't possibly have "a lot of narrow spikes corresponding to the data points" when there are 10,000 data points and only 512 values in the density array!

Comment: @whuber, of course the trapeziodal rule is working fine for what it is supposed to do (integrating by lin. interp.), but that is a way of understanding why we are consistently getting higher area estimates from the small bw kernels. It is not just a matter of higher variance of the estimate due to lack of precision. The bias for higher estimates is apparently due to the convex nature of the kernels. I'd love to know if convexity has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @high You're not following me.  As far as I can see, this explanation is simply wrong: the gross failure in the integration is not due to errors in the trapezoidal rule.  **No** method of integration will work because the sampling frequency of the density is far too coarse.  The problem lies in a sampling bias, not in the integration.  This is wholly unrelated to convexity.

Comment: Looking at these graphs, I am now thinking that the problem is with `density` rather than with `integrate.xy`. With N=10000 and bw=1e-6, you would **have** to see a comb with a height of each tooth of about 1e6, and the teeth being denser around 0. Instead, you still see a recognizable bell-shaped curve. So `density` is cheating on you, or at least it should be used differently with tiny bandwidths: `n` should be about (range of data)/(bw) rather than the default `n=512`. The intergrator must be picking up one of these huge values that `density` returns by an unhappy coincidence.

Comment: Of course the problem is not with integrate.xy, it is supposed to integrate a set of data, which it does correctly. There are no "errors" in the trapezoidal rule.

Comment: I think it is not related to convexity since using a kernel that is not convex, such as "triabgular" also has the same bias. It is indeed related to sampling bias. I still contend that it is simply not a lack of precision ("can't do better with 512 pts"), but a systematic bias in the density function to oversample the peaks. Does anyone know where one could find the source code for the density function?

Answer (score 1):

Ive been integrating using the automatic bandwidth and getting answers ranging from .1 to 7 , not particularly trustworty.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/340011)

Answer (score 0):

##### Use the `KDE` function in the `utilties` package instead

*Note: This answer is adapted from a silmiar answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71072/580904#580904).*

The problem you are encountering is that the `density` function in the `stats` package gives you an output that is just a vector of density values at a finite number of points --- it is not actually giving you a full density function that you can integrate effectively.  This is a reasonable way to give a density output if you just want to plot the density reasonable well, but as you can see, it leads to a value that is slightly different to one when you try to integrate it.

To get around this deficiency, you can use the `KDE` function in the `utilties` package.  This function generates the KDE in the same way as the `density` function in `R`,$^\dagger$ but instead of producing an output computed over a relatively small set of points, it produces an output that includes the *probability functions* for the KDE.  You can also call the function in such a way that it loads those probability functions directly to the global environment, so that you can easily call them just like any other density function in `R`.  This will give you a full density function that you can call at any set of points, and also a cumulative distribution function where the integration of the density has already been done for you.

Below I give an example of how to generate the KDE using this function, and how to call the cumulative distribution function over an arbitrary set of values.  As you can see, the `KDE` function produces a set of probability functions (`dkde`, `pkde`, `qkde`, and `rkde`) that can be called just like the probability functions for any of the pre-programmed families of distributions.  This allows you to compute the cumulative distribution from `pkde` at any point you want, including points that are far outside the data range used to generate the KDE.

```
#Load the package
library(utilities)

#Generate some mock data
set.seed(1)
DATA <- rnorm(40)

#Create a KDE and show its output
MY_KDE <- KDE(DATA, to.environment = TRUE)
MY_KDE

  Kernel Density Estimator (KDE) 
 
  Computed from 40 data points in the input 'DATA'
  Estimated bandwidth = 0.367412  
  Input degrees-of-freedom = Inf 
 
  Probability functions for the KDE are the following: 
 
      Density function:                   dkde * 
      Distribution function:              pkde * 
      Quantile function:                  qkde * 
      Random generation function:         rkde * 
 
  * This function is presently loaded in the global environment

#Call the CDF over a set of points (including points far in the tails)
POINTS <- -10:10
pkde(POINTS)
 [1] 1.489573e-101  4.685332e-78  9.132757e-58  1.112228e-40  8.584043e-27  4.322183e-16
 [7]  1.529301e-08  4.819333e-04  3.326124e-02  1.236576e-01  4.251039e-01  8.352227e-01
[13]  9.927698e-01  9.999976e-01  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
[19]  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
```

From the outputs of the CDF you can see that the density function integrates to one over the full range.  (If you're unsure, just call `pkde(Inf)` to see the CDF value integrating over the whole range.)

---

$^\dagger$ The `KDE` function has the advantage of giving a more useful output (in my opinion) but it is not as general as the `density` function in the base package.  It does not accomodate as wide a range of kernel types or bandwidth estimation methods.  Both functions can produce a KDE using the normal kernel.

Answer (score -1):

That's okay, you can fix it shifting and scaling; add the smallest number such that the density is non-negative, then multiply the whole thing by a constant such that the area is unity. This is the easy way.

The optimal $L_2$ solution involves "water pouring"; finding the constant $c$ such that $\left[\phi(x)-c\right]^+$ integrates to unity.

Comment: Notice that the question is rather on *why* the `density` function does not produce the "proper" density that integrates to 1 - rather then on how to fix it.