# Calculate tail probabilities from density() call in R

Tags: r, density-estimation

This question concerns how to implement the following problem in R.

```
x = rnorm(1000)
hist(x,freq=FALSE)
lines(density(x))
```

How would you calculate the upper (or lower) tail probability for a given cutoff (e.g. +1) given the density estimate above? NOTE: the following solution isn't good enough. I need the calculation based on the smoothed density curve, i.e. an integral of the curve, not the empirical histogram.

```
sum(x>1)/length(x)
```

Also please do not suggest the use any of the standard `pnorm` functions because they are only correct if the underlying distribution is correctly specified. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take the same approach as @Flounderer, but exploit another feature of **R**'s `density()` function; namely the `from` and `to` arguments, which restrict the density estimation to the region enclosed by the two arguments. This results in the same density estimates as running the function without `from` and/or `to`, but by restricting the range of the density estimate to the region of interest, we focus *all* of the `n` evaluation points on the region of interest.

```
set.seed(1)
x <-rnorm(1000)
hist(x,freq=FALSE)
lines( dens <- density(x) )
lines( dens2 <- density(x, from = 1, n = 1024), col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

This produces

[image]

The red line is to illustrate that the density estimates in `dens` and `dens2` are the same for the region of interest.

Then you can follow the approach @Flounderer used to evaluate the tail probability:

```
> with(dens2, sum(y * diff(x)[1]))
[1] 0.1680759
```

The advantage of this approach is to expend the `n` observations at which `density()` evaluates the KDE all on the region of interest. The larger `n` the higher the resolution that you have in evaluating the tail probability.

Note from `?density` that given the FFT used in the implementation, having `n` as a multiple of 2 is advantageous.

Answer (score 7):

The `density` function returns an object with various properties. You can access the $x$ and $y$ values using `density(x)$x` and `density(x)$y`. So you can do it like this:

```
set.seed(100)
x <- rnorm(1000)
d <- density(x)
x0 <- 1
idx <- which(abs(d$x-x0)==min(abs(d$x-x0)))
approx.tail.prob <- sum(d$y[idx:length(d$x)] * diff(d$x)[1])
```

This is just an approximation based on a Riemann sum. You could get a better approximation using another numerical technique, such as the Trapezium Rule or Simpson's Rule. But once you know how to get at `density(x)$x` and `density(x)$y`, it's straightforward to work out how to do these.

You could even use the R `integrate` function, maybe like this:

```
f <- function(x0) d$y[which(abs(d$x-x0) == min(abs(d$x-x0)))[1]]
```

and then:

```
integrate(Vectorize(f), 1, max(d$x))
```

Comment: For some reason this code doesn't work if I use `set.seed(1)`. Gives the error message: Error in integrate(Vectorize(f), 1, max(d$x)) : maximum number of subdivisions reached

Comment: Try `integrate(Vectorize(f), 1, max(d$x), subdivisions=1000)`, or use the other answer; it looks better!

Answer (score 5):

By definition, given a "bandwidth" $h$ and a kernel density $k,$ the KDE of a data vector $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is

$$f(x; \mathbf{x}, h, k) = \frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n k\left(\frac{x - x_i}{h}\right).$$

Consequently the distribution function (left tail probability function) is its integral,

> $$F(x; \mathbf{x}, h, K) = \frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^x k\left(\frac{t - x_i}{h}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K(t-x_i; h)$$

where $K$ is the integral of $k,$

$$K(x) = \frac{1}{h}\int_{-\infty}^x k\left(\frac{t}{h}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

By default, `density` uses a Gaussian (Normal) kernel: that is, $k$ is implemented as `dnorm` and $K$ as `pnorm`.  **This leads to an extremely compact and precise solution:**

```R
pkde <- Vectorize(function(x, data, bw) mean(pnorm(x, data, bw)), "x")
```

The arguments of  `pkde` are the point `x` of evaluation, the data vector `data` $=\mathbf{x},$ and the bandwidth `bw` $=h.$  For instance, the right tail probability at the value $x=1$ in the example is obtained by storing the result of `density` in order to fetch `bw`:

```R
obj <- density(x)
1 - pkde(1, x, obj$bw)
```

The answer (for the question's sample data) will be close to $0.16,$ depending on the specific values that were generated.

---

**Some comments about the use of `pnorm` may be of interest.**  `pnorm` appears here *because it describes your kernel.*  Any other solution will be equivalent to this one.  This one is the most precise of any possible solution because it does not require interpolation.  It will be inferior in terms of computational complexity when $n$ is large, because it requires one evaluation of `pnorm` for each data point.  It will be greatly superior to any conceivable alternative when `n` is small.  Indeed, *it doesn't even require the KDE to be computed:* it only needs you to determine what bandwidth you want to use.

**Here is a more interesting example,** showing how `pkde` can be used to plot the entire cumulative distribution of the KDE for a decidedly non-Normal dataset.

```R
set.seed(17)
X <- c(rexp(500), rgamma(500, 30))
obj <- density(X)
curve(pkde(x, X, obj$bw), min(X), max(X), lwd=2, main="Left tail kernel probability")
hist(X, breaks=100)
```

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 1):

##### You can do this with the `KDE` function in the `utilties` package

For this type of problem, you can use the `KDE` function in the `utilties` package.  This function generates the KDE in the same way as the `density` function in `R`,$^\dagger$ but instead of producing an output computed over a relatively small set of points, it produces an output that includes the *probability functions* for the KDE.  You can also call the function in such a way that it loads those probability functions directly to the global environment, so that you can easily call them just like any other density function in `R`.

Below I give an example of how to generate the KDE using this function, and how to call the cumulative distribution function over an arbitrary set of values.  As you can see, the `KDE` function produces a set of probability functions (`dkde`, `pkde`, `qkde`, and `rkde`) that can be called just like the probability functions for any of the pre-programmed families of distributions.  This allows you to compute the cumulative distribution from `pkde` at any point you want, including points that are far outside the data range used to generate the KDE.

```
#Load the package
library(utilities)

#Generate some mock data
set.seed(1)
DATA <- rnorm(40)

#Create a KDE and show its output
MY_KDE <- KDE(DATA, to.environment = TRUE)
MY_KDE

  Kernel Density Estimator (KDE) 
 
  Computed from 40 data points in the input 'DATA'
  Estimated bandwidth = 0.367412  
  Input degrees-of-freedom = Inf 
 
  Probability functions for the KDE are the following: 
 
      Density function:                   dkde * 
      Distribution function:              pkde * 
      Quantile function:                  qkde * 
      Random generation function:         rkde * 
 
  * This function is presently loaded in the global environment

#Call the CDF over a set of points (including points far in the tails)
POINTS <- -10:10
pkde(POINTS)
 [1] 1.489573e-101  4.685332e-78  9.132757e-58  1.112228e-40  8.584043e-27  4.322183e-16
 [7]  1.529301e-08  4.819333e-04  3.326124e-02  1.236576e-01  4.251039e-01  8.352227e-01
[13]  9.927698e-01  9.999976e-01  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
[19]  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
```

Note that if you want upper-tail probabilities then you can just set `lower.tail = FALSE` when you call the cumulative distribution function using `pkde`.

---

$^\dagger$ The `KDE` function has the advantage of giving a more useful output (in my opinion) but it is not as general as the `density` function in the base package.  It does not accomodate as wide a range of kernel types or bandwidth estimation methods.  Both functions can produce a KDE using the normal kernel.