# Increase accuracy of density() and integrate() in R density estimations

Tags: r, probability, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

How can I increase the accuracy of density() and integrate() in R density estimations? I must use the integrate() function, because I need it further downstream. I already increased n to 2^15 and lowered the bw, with however little to no effect. So i know density() is maybe causing the problem, however I don't know how to optimize the parameters appropriately.

```
thetaDensity = approxfun(density(n=512^2, bw="SJ", dat, from=min(dat), to=max(dat)))
integrate(thetaDensity, min(dat),max(dat))$value

[1] 0.8174283
```

Shouldn't that be 1?

This is biological data, and I must be as accurate as possible.
Thanks for your time!

Here is my data:

```
dat <- c(0.142868118805991, 0.0100035023202872, 0.0401594616949269, 
0.092903018625562, 0, 0.00550175841299198, 0.0104936896519906, 
0.0162563247555232, 0.0261780104712042, 0.0446927374301676, 0.0437158469945355, 
0, 0.0256739324023266, 0, 0.0524859263143329, 0.0286828429995437, 
0.0217503138739799, 0.0425292482278217, 0.0195756152112436, 0.0887902940534519, 
0.0182101620775831, 0.0806451612903226, 0.0408118401579774, 0.0213595008362051, 
0.0298917390995122, 0.0381607861172393, 0.0136593466910849, 0, 
0, 0.010989010989011, 0.00884189270929602, 0, 0.00366300366300366, 
0, 0.0032967032967033, 0, 0, 0, 0.00183150183150183, 0.00231677154754078, 
0.0126715637223708, 0, 0.0875943333774659, 0.0100502512562814, 
0.00402010050251256, 0.00701099773736195, 0.0484806428215284, 
0, 0, 0.00530976772111524, 0.0083011583011583, 0, 0.0010989010989011, 
0.0260707635009311, 0.0274725274725275, 0.0662983425414365, 0.0383705040512662, 
0.0137132382563855, 0.0441553093414595, 0.0167928676111383, 0.00660413646780633, 
0.0149999964154077, 0.00529100529100529, 0.0146306749650215, 
0.0017636684303351, 0.0125776397515528, 0.0860355114498761, 0.0151345955366056, 
0.0119274948314761, 0.018018018018018, 0.001194743130227, 0.010752688172043, 
0, 0.00347739692001987, 0.0364298724954463, 0.00500082907490315, 
0.0322308843350133, 0.00531914893617021, 0.00273224043715847, 
0.0821254715545692, 0.0769230769230769, 0.0036036036036036, 0.00325109856827605, 
0.00308052910956291, 0.00579974973682642, 0.0231438454757607, 
0.0102380589817776, 0.00954946137028829, 0.0199530029718709, 
0.00897265304044965, 0, 0.0149812734082397, 0.00473710095680944, 
0.00211640211640212, 0, 0.00302343159486017, 0, 0, 0.0288288288288288, 
0.0160558169205728, 0.00272734511864947, 0.00738360060329874, 
0.00645596057491486, 0.00366300366300366, 0.0183150183150183, 
0.0197195729635002, 0.0677655677655678, 0.0631595282433271, 0.0384615384615385, 
0, 0.0271739130434783, 0, 0, 0.0101811746501697, 0.0425576204029243, 
0.095989646520324, 0, 0.00297705736604188, 0, 0, 0.00555555555555556, 
0, 0.00767172310650572, 0.00502967271872613, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00365299545627414, 
0.012774803012494, 0, 0.00947119179163378, 0.0182501817985668, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0268830491254085, 0.0053475935828877, 0.0372340425531915, 
0.0313620071684588, 0, 0.0163934426229508, 0.0232657451013076, 
0.0159574468085106, 0.036579995596389, 0, 0, 0.0182149362477231, 
0, 0.0273224043715847, 0, 0.0163934426229508, 0, 0.0248855728467472, 
0.0112359550561798, 0.00374531835205993, 0, 0, 0.0053475935828877, 
0.0111111111111111, 0, 0.0108108108108108, 0.010989010989011, 
0, 0.0165016501650165, 0.0152284263959391, 0, 0, 0.0369967793880837, 
0, 0, 0.0157790927021696, 0, 0.00546448087431694, 0.00819672131147541, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0280898876404494, 0, 0.00218579234972678, 0, 0.0163934426229508, 
0.00549450549450549, 0.131868131868132, 0, 0.00380952380952381, 
0.0349423951468407, 0.00285714285714286, 0, 0, 0.00588235294117647, 
0, 0.00946275946275946, 0, 0.198895027624309, 0, 0.0174008138885438, 
0.00942431715548377, 0.0165745856353591, 0, 0, 0.0441988950276243, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00721688860797386, 0, 0.0317460317460317, 0.0145719489981785, 
0.00546448087431694, 0.0274725274725275, 0.00820423407932619, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00803606986402685, 0.0213903743315508, 0.0242293906810036, 
0.00540540540540541, 0, 0.0163934426229508, 0.003584229390681, 
0.021505376344086, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0163934426229508, 
0, 0, 0.00546448087431694, 0, 0, 0.00662993544209014, 0.0109289617486339, 
0, 0.0124903105026838, 0, 0, 0.0842696629213483, 0.0033500837520938, 
0, 0.0104240701255627, 0, 0, 0, 0.00552486187845304, 0, 0.00364298724954463, 
0.0110570522172732, 0.0155696577661229, 0.00941756012749928, 
0.00311217881667587, 0.0023077597663233, 0.0109289617486339, 
0, 0.00546448087431694, 0, 0.0710659898477157, 0.0617977528089888, 
0, 0, 0.0698924731182796, 0.0123899561999142)
```

possibly related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697776/area-under-probability-density-curve-is-not-equal-to-1

[Area under the “pdf” in kernel density estimation in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14061/area-under-the-pdf-in-kernel-density-estimation-in-r)

Comment: The integral of a kernel density estimate over the range of the data will always be *strictly less than* $1$ because it omits the density assigned to values beyond the range. Also, with a function as variable as yours, it's almost hopeless to try a linear approximation (which is what `approxfun` does).  At the very least, use `splinefun`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I will give it a try and report back. I know it's never exactly 1, however 20% deviation strikes me as a bit too much.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you believe you need to integrate a kernel density estimate. There might be a better approach.

Comment: I have a binary vector representing my data (length~ 600). I want to cluster the data by distances between the vectors. (This usually works well, with exceptions.) I want to show how many vectors cannot be clustered because thier internal custer distance would be the same or higher than the average distance between clusters. Therefore I overlapped two density functions (distances within cluster and between cluster) and integrate the overlap. I know the correct cluster for 70% of my data. I try to assign 30% of the data to clusters that have an internal distance smaller than to the next cluster